# How can I change opportunity owner field to be anyone from the users?

Tags: community, opportunity, page-layout

When we create a new opportunity there is the opportunity owner field. Is there any chance that I can select a different user while creating an opportunity? Right now it is just a fixed field on my name (the user account I am using to create an opportunity), but for example I am creating an opportunity for someone else and instead of changing the opportunity owner to that person after creation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this out of the box.

You can upvote this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpuOAAS) that is specific to Opportunity Owner

In terms of what you can do now:

1. Do nothing and have the user manually edit it after creation
2. Create another lookup to User on the Opportunity Users can fill out that you then copy over to the real Owner field before insert.
3. If there's any logic to this (assign to team member x, etc) - you can set up a Process Builder, Flow, or Trigger to update the owner before insert.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could check out the myriad of options on the AppExchange.  A (currently free) solution is SuperRoundRobin which will do precisely what you need.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FR4MkUAL